# Has anyone got Datatables 1.7.x to actually work with ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, datatables

Is there a demo somewhere how to use Datatables 1.7.x with ASP.NET MVC 2 ?

Is saw an early demo somewhere but the Datatables API has since been updated. Does anyone have working code for implementation ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using this in a project soon.

Here are some recources that may help:

http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

http://datatablesmvc.codeplex.com/

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160314045528/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/paulwhit/archive/2009/03/28/walkthrough-full-example-of-using-mvccontrib-grid-with-jquery-datatable.aspx)

http://datatables.net/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=678

http://weblogs.asp.net/zowens/archive/2010/01/19/jquery-datatables-plugin-meets-c.aspx

http://www.digitalinfamy.com/dev-for-noobs/sexy-datatables-for-asp-mv